# "'x' and 'y' lengths differ" error when trying to plot two columns from same dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following R code

```
library("ggplot2")

GDP_data <- read.csv("US GDP.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",")
GDP_data = data.frame(GDP_data)
names(GDP_data) <- GDP_data[1,]
GDP_data <- GDP_data[-1,]

plot(x=GDP_data["level-current"], y=GDP_data["date"], type="l",col="red", main="")
```

summary(GDP_data) returns these columns:

```
date           level-current      level-chained      change-current     change-chained    
 Length:86          Length:86          Length:86          Length:86          Length:86         
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode :character
```

It tells me the error when I try to plot it: `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :    'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

When I try to use `length()` function it gives me [1] for both GDP_data["level-current"] and GDP_data["date"], although they are 86.

Comment: You should use double square brackets to extract the vector that you want to plot from a data frame,  e.g. `GDP_data[["level-current"]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me:

```
plot(y=GDP_data[["level-current"]], x=GDP_data[["date"]], type="l")
```

Somehow adding more square brackets worked and it's now plotting beatifully.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49699955/11856430) for example for an explanation  why you need double brackets :)